# Combine JSON files with grunt-contrib-concat

Tags: javascript, json, concatenation, gruntjs

I'm looking for the best way to combine json files in a folder.

With HTML, CSS and JavaScript this is pretty easy since you don't need a separator or only a single `;`.
However, with JSON, we need something more to make it a valid JSON object.

One way would be to concatenate the files with `,` and wrap everything in an array. I'm wondering if there is an better/easier way to do this.

### Gruntfile.js

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        json: {
            src: ['src/**/*.json'],
            dest: 'dist/combined.json',
            options: {
              ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### src/file1.json

```js
{
    "number": 1
}
```

### src/file2.json

```js
{
    "number": 2
}
```

### dist/combined.json

This would be the desired outcome:

```js
{
    "numbers": [
        {
            "number": 1
        },
        {
            "number": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So basically you are trying to merge on same level keys?

Comment: @DanKanze just trying to merge JSON files into another JSON file. Doesn't really matter what the contents of those files is.

Comment: @debuzze So that means you are trying to preserve key heirachy right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the [banner](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#banner) and [footer](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat#footer) options.

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
        json: {
            src: ['src/**/*.json'],
            dest: 'dist/combined.json',
            options: {
                // Added to the top of the file
                banner: '{"numbers": [',
                // Will be added at the end of the file
                footer: "]}",
                separator: ','
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So this actually works? Wouldn't this just create duplicate objects/properties? I see how you've hard-coded the "numbers" object in the target, but it seems like this wouldn't work without doing that. I found this question because I just created a grunt task to create JSON/YAML "manifests", https://github.com/assemble/assemble-manifest, and I'm thinking of doing something similar to what you're describing. If I can get more info about use cases it might help me decide the best way to merge objects and properties.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [grunt-merge-json](https://github.com/rse/grunt-merge-json) for that.

Usage Example:

Assuming we have the following types of source JSON files:

```
src/foo/foo-en.json:
{
    "foo": {
        "title": "The Foo",
        "name":  "A wonderful component"
    }
}
src/bar/bar-en.json:
{
    "bar": {
        "title": "The Bar",
        "name":  "An even more wonderful component"
    }
}
```

Assuming we want to generate the following destination JSON file:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "title": "The Foo",
        "name":  "A wonderful component"
    },
    "bar": {
        "title": "The Bar",
        "name":  "An even more wonderful component"
    }
}
```

Single file per target variant

```
grunt.initConfig({
    "merge-json": {
        "en": {
            src: [ "src/**/*-en.json" ],
            dest: "www/en.json"
        },
        "de": {
            src: [ "src/**/*-de.json" ],
            dest: "www/de.json"
        }`enter code here`
    }
});
```

Multiple files per target variant

```
grunt.initConfig({
    "merge-json": {
        "i18n": {
            files: {
                "www/en.json": [ "src/**/*-en.json" ],
                "www/de.json": [ "src/**/*-de.json" ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dedicated and JSON oriented plugin to handle that. Not just an arbitrary string concat.

Take a look at https://github.com/rse/grunt-merge-json or https://github.com/shinnn/grunt-merge-data